# Remove consecutive duplicate rows from a table

Tags: sql-server, database, loops, duplicates, ssms

I am stuck on a problem. I want to remove consecutive duplicate records in the table,
I,e, in the below table I want to calculate the total cost without consecutive duplication.
Like, row 3 should be removed as it is consecutively duplicated with row 2 as all 3 column data is the same.
And same is the case in the second group, row 7 should be removed as it is a duplication of 6.
The total cost at the end should be 10.

How can I do it in SSMS?

| ClaimID | ClaimLine | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M0001R1616878951 | 2 | 10 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 2 | -10 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 2 | -10 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 3 | 10 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 3 | -10 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 3 | 10 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 3 | 10 |

I searched for this problem and tried lead and lag keywords but didnt work.

Comment: Are those the only columns in the table? Without some other data, there's no meaning to "consecutive" - SQL tables are unordered sets.

Comment: @Mureinik yes these are the only columns I extracted from another table using group by and this data will be ordered always by ClaimID and ClaimLine columns.

Comment: Can you share sample data for the `ClaimID` and `ClaimLine` in this sample? Without them, I fear the question may be meaningless.

Comment: The above table in the question has the sample data in it. I'm afraid if the table in the question is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prepared an example for your issue and it might be solution for that.

I used [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) expressions to generate row_number and filter for duplicate rows.

Preparing the example data:

```
DECLARE @vClaims TABLE (
    ClaimID     NVARCHAR(16),
    ClaimLine   SMALLINT,
    Cost        SMALLINT
)

INSERT INTO @vClaims
VALUES
    ('M0001R1616878951', 2, 10),
    ('M0001R1616878951', 2, -10),
    ('M0001R1616878951', 2, -10),
    ('M0001R1616878951', 3, 10),
    ('M0001R1616878951', 3, -10),
    ('M0001R1616878951', 3, 10),
    ('M0001R1616878951', 3, 10)
```

And the query script:

```
;WITH CTE_ClaimsWithSort AS (
    SELECT
        ClaimID,
        ClaimLine,
        Cost,
        RowNumber   = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
        @vClaims
), CTE_ClaimsFiltered AS (
    SELECT 
        ClaimID,
        ClaimLine,
        Cost,
        RowNumber,
        isDuplicate     = IIF(
                            LAG(ClaimID) OVER(ORDER BY RowNumber) = ClaimID
                            AND LAG(ClaimLine) OVER(ORDER BY RowNumber) = ClaimLine
                            AND LAG(Cost) OVER(ORDER BY RowNumber) = Cost
                        , 1, 0)
    FROM 
        CTE_ClaimsWithSort
)
SELECT 
    ClaimID,
    ClaimLine,
    Cost,
    RowNumber,
    isDuplicate
FROM 
    CTE_ClaimsFiltered
WHERE
    isDuplicate = 0
```

First part of cte: generate row_numbers for your example data. If you have a date column you can use instead of it.

Second part of cte: find and filter duplicate rows by ClaimID, ClaimLine and Cost with IIF expression

The result:

| ClaimID | ClaimLine | Cost | RowNumber | isDuplicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M0001R1616878951 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 2 | -10 | 2 | 0 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 3 | 10 | 4 | 0 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 3 | -10 | 5 | 0 |
| M0001R1616878951 | 3 | 10 | 6 | 0 |

Comment: It worked, I'm honored!